# How do I check if a Sharepoint Document Library has the Require Approval flag set, using the Sharepoint API?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-api

It would also be useful to be able to check the "Requires Checkout" flag as well.  I thought it might be a property on the SPDocumentLibrary object, but I can't see it.

Do I need to look in one of the admin namespaces...?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Require approval is represented by the Boolean property EnableModeration on the Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList class. Require checkout is controlled by the property ForceCheckout on the same class.
Remember to also call the Update() method on the SPList class to save your changes to the database.